# Using nested/embedded documents in Mongoengine with Python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I want to use nested values inside Mongodb and from the documentation i understand this is done through Embedded documents. If there are any other ways please tell me.

I have the current code:

```
class compute_instances_subtype(EmbeddedDocument):
    label_name = StringField()

class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    author = StringField(required=True)
    tags = ListField(StringField(max_length=30))
    compute_instances = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(compute_instances_subtype))

post = Post(title="Quora rocks", author="Ross", tags=['tutorial', 'how-to'])

add_test0_label = compute_instances_subtype()
add_test0_label.title = "test0"
add_test0_label.label_name= "value"

add_test1_label= compute_instances_subtype()
add_test1_label.title = "test1"
add_test1_label.label_name= "value"

post.compute_instances.append(add_test0_label)
post.compute_instances.append(add_test1_label)
post.save()
```

But my issue is that the document does not have a name for the Objects of the compute_instances field, it just says 0 and 1:

> ```
> id : 60fec94dbb81d98abb557523
> title : Quora rocks
> author : Ross
> tags : compute_instances : Array
> 0 : Object
> label_name : value
> 1 : Object
> label_name : value
> ```

I want to have 0 named test0 and 1 named test1.
Please guide me on how to achieve that.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you use to print the object, but here are a few comments that might help you:

- your `compute_instances_subtype` class has no `title` field that is set, so when you set `add_test0_label.title = "test0"`, it's just added to the python object but it's not being saved in the database when you call `.save()`.
- 0 and 1 that you see in your output are the indexes of the Object in the `compute_instances` array

Here is a simplified example that might also be helpful:

```
class ComputeInstancesSubtype(EmbeddedDocument):
    label_name = StringField()
    title = StringField()

class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    compute_instances = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(ComputeInstancesSubtype))

nested1 = ComputeInstancesSubtype(title='something0', label_name='test0')
nested2 = ComputeInstancesSubtype(title='something1', label_name='test1')
post = Post(title="Quora rocks", compute_instances = [nested1, nested2])
post.save()

print(Post._get_collection().find_one())    # print it in its raw format
```

returns

```
{'_id': ObjectId('61071c5e3686c4066dadbc05'),
 'title': 'Quora rocks',
 'compute_instances': [{'label_name': 'test0', 'title': 'something0'},
                      {'label_name': 'test1', 'title': 'something1'}]
}
```